# Hibernate does not consider field to insert

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0, composite-primary-key

Good,

I'm new to HIbernate and I'm going through a problem and I need support to try to solve it.

I have a Client class, this class contains composite key.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Clientes")
@IdClass(ClientePK.class)
public class Cliente implements Serializable {

    //@EmbeddedId
    //private ClientePK clientePK;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "Id_Cliente", nullable = false, length = 15)
    private long idCliente;

    @Id
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "Loja", nullable = false)
    private Loja loja;

}

public class ClientePK implements Serializable {

    private long idCliente;
    private Loja loja;
}
```

Then I have a ClientClass class that also contains compound key

```
@Entity
@Table(name = “Clientes_Historicos”)
@IdClass(ClienteHistoricoPK.class)
public class ClienteHistorico implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Resolvable(colName = "Id. Cliente Histórico")
    @Column(name = "Id_Cliente_Historico", nullable = false)
    private Long idClienteHistorico;

    @Id
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "Loja", nullable = false)
    private Loja loja;

    @Resolvable(colName = "Cliente")
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "id_cliente", referencedColumnName = "Id_Cliente", nullable = false, insertable = true)
        ,
        @JoinColumn(name = "loja", referencedColumnName = "loja", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    })
    @MapsId("loja")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Cliente cliente;

}
```

I used the @MapsId Annotation ("store") to indicate that the store field of the primary key should be used with the FK field of the client connection itself.

It occurs that when performing the insert in ClientHistorico the client field is not being taken into consideration to be inserted.

```
Informações:   Hibernate: insert into Clientes_Historicos (Data, Tipo, Usuario, Id_Cliente_Historico, Loja) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
WARN:   SQL Error: 1400, SQLState: 23000
ERROR:   ORA-01400: não é possível inserir NULL em ("MARTINELLO"."CLIENTES_HISTORICOS"."ID_CLIENTE")

Informações:   HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
ERROR:   HHH000346: Error during managed flush [org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement]
```

thank you.

Comment: Should the code constructing the objects to be saved. Have to you set the cliente reference on the  ClienteHistorico  instance?

Comment: The object is loaded with a client reference and is still not sent to keep the annotation leading to an annotation MapsId it takes the field to persist